# Configuring HAproxy to Mbed tls implementation of TLS

Tags: ssl, haproxy, mbedtls

How can I configure HAproxy to a specific implementation of TLS, I mean for example " Mbed TLS" which is a security library dedicated to the embedded systems.

Thanks in advance

Comment: wolfSSL has a solution to compile with USE_WOLFSSL as an alternative to USE_OPENSSL. It is not yet merged into haproxy proper unfortunately. You can contact support@wolfssl.com to inquire about their custom solution. **DICLAIMER: I work for wolfSSL Inc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment

I contacted HAproxy stuff and they replied with the following:

" You can't.

Haproxy supports OpenSSL, and we try to make it work with OpenSSL
forks like LibreSSL and boringssl, but a different library is not
supported.
"